# Password generator not working properly

Tags: python, passwords

first of all i hope this is allowed. I lost the password of a very important personal file and i'm trying to forcebrute it so i can get it back, however while trying to find codes to make it work i found this one, but it's semi-broken. It would find the password if it's "fg" but not if it's "gf", can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

```
import traceback
from itertools import combinations

lookingfor = "fg"

try:
letritas = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
for c in combinations(letritas, 2):
  combinacion1 = str(c).replace("', '", "")
  combinacion2 = combinacion1.replace("('", "")
  combinacion3 = combinacion2.replace("')", "")
  print("Trying: ["+combinacion3+"]")
  if lookingfor == combinacion3:
      print("Found on: "+combinacion3)
      break
```

Assuming that works and creates all combinations, each time i get a wrong one on the real code, i got a OSError, i wonder if there's a way to set that Except OSERROR: ignore the error and continue with the loop until find the right one.

**Edit: this is python 3.3.2**

Comment: You want permutations, not combinations.

Comment: Permutations, right. Now it works perfect and generate all possible answers :D. Now the part 2: how do i make the loop continues trying different passwords if i get OSError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permutations did the trick and i found a way to Repeat the code excluding the tried one, that's

```
  if not combinacion3 in comprobadas:
    print("Trying: ["+combinacion3+"]")
    comprobadas.append(combinacion3)
```

That way it stores all tried ones and won't try it on next attempt.